# background-image not displaying in header

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I'm building a website in Wordpress, using the theme from musicmakertheme.com.

I'm trying to add some css to the theme, specifically a bg-image in the header, and the image won't show.
I included the entire added css, in case something there might be causeing the conflict...

```
.navigation_holder, .header_holder
{
background-color: none !important;
background: none !important;
background-image: url('http://beyondyoumusic.com/wp-  
content/uploads/2016/12/The-Wheel-slim.png') !important; 
background-position: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Content BG */
#beat_player, #beat_player_info , #beat_player_description ,
#beat_player_top, .beat_player_player  
{  border: none !important; background: none  !important;}
#main , .widget ,  #beat_player 
{ background: rgb(255, 250, 250); background: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.8);}`
```

Comment: remove 'background: none !important';

Comment: If I do that, it will go from transparent to showing a background color, but not the image

Comment: @gnmc remove that line like ovokuro said. And put `background-color: transparent;`, or use the [rgba format](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_colors.asp) (the alpha value will be 0).